# libGDX app to .exe?

Tags: java, build, libgdx

I have a libGDX project that I want to be able to run from a .exe file on my desktop.

So far I can only run it over DesktopLauncher inside my Android Studio.

Whats the simplest way to build a .exe file out of my project?

I can build .jar file but it won't run on double-click. Does that mean I need to make a wrapper for display or something?

I'm new to libgdx and android studio, and I just need to deploy my first simple app as a standalone file on desktop.

Comment: See https://github.com/libgdx/packr/blob/master/README.md

Comment: And https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Excelsior-JET-and-libGDX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two choices:

1- Packr, which packages your jar files along with the java jre and creates an executable on Windows, Linux or MAC (https://github.com/libgdx/packr)

2- Excelsior JET, which recompiles the entire java code to native executable. This option cost money, though (http://www.excelsiorjet.com/)

Comment: Excelsior JET, Standard Edition is free now: https://www.excelsiorjet.com/buy#free-std